# HMVC 3 Is out and working codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

**I know this is not a Question but a note:**

I thought this would be use full for codeigniter hmvc users. Just found out that Wiredesignz HMVC has now released HMVC 3 version working https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads

Works with codeigniter 3

Works fine but make sure when use controllers and librarys that files are capitalized. example `Welcome.php`

Comment: Have you try with session?

Comment: @goFrendiAsgard Yes have tried with sessions now work fine.